# Cyrillic symbols do not show in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a script that takes a POST (HTTP) request and sends a response. If the POST data has english characters, they are returned/displayed normally. But cyrillic chars look like this:

```
������ ������ �������������� ������
```

My Python script is as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print('Content-type: text/html\n')
import cgi
from imp import reload
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
text2 = form.getfirst("postvar1", "не задано")
print(text2)
```

I use a custom server script

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8080)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

The python script is saved as UTF-8.

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Do you have this line in your script`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`?

Comment: Yes i have # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/cgi.html) _use the encoding keyword parameter set to the value of the encoding defined for the document. It is usually contained in the META tag in the HEAD section of the HTML document or by the Content-Type header)._ You may need `cgi.FieldStorage(type='utf-8')` or whatever is in the content header.

Comment: `Content-type: text/html\n` -> `Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n`

Comment: How exactly do you run this and get the output? It would also be useful to check your terminal encoding with `print(sys.stdout.encoding)`.

Comment: I guess that was confusing..! Are you hitting this with a web browser? You could use a script `import requests;print(requests.get('http://your.url/here').content[:1024])` to get something to post here.

Comment: @nick_gabpe Python 3 does not need the encoding declaration because Python 3 is utf-8 by default.

Comment: As others suggested, either your web browsers encodes it wrong, or your terminal. You can set the encoding manually in both. In the browser it is usually under "View". Google the rest. Also, watch [Pragmatic Unicode, or, How do I stop the pain?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc). It's the best explanation on the web about what is going on with Python and Unicode and Encodings. After that you'll never have to ask such a question again, I promise.

Comment: @Daniel thanks, I always forget about 3.x features.